# Access error 3022 on open with no local tables

Tags: ms-access

I have a database file (that I have current backups of) fail to open with error 3022. All of the tables used are remote, SQL Server or access. My backup database file can open with no issues and we have no data lost. I tried to do a compact and repair on the file remotely using application.CompactRepair but that fails giving me error 31523. I tried using the command line and opening the file with the /compact switch, but that also failed.

Why would I be getting the 3022 error just opening the database file?

Comment: Does this database have an autoexec macro or start-up form set that is trying to insert data somewhere? The description of Access error 3022 is "Run-time error '3022': The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship". Have you tried opening the database with the Shift key held down to bypass the start-up settings?

Comment: I tried holding shift, no dice. Before access even looks like it loaded the file, it shows the error twice in a row. There is no autoexec macro, and the on load for the switchboard form queries active directory to figure out who is using the application and sets some visibility properties. Then  it runs a function that disables closing the application with the upper right corner x.

Comment: So do you have access to the start-up settings? Can you remove the start-up switchboard form? Or can you get into design view for the switchboard and edit the `on load` code to skip all the start-up stuff? You say this code queries AD to find out who is using the app - does this involve adding any data into tables? You also say you can open the backup file with no issues - does this file point to the same SQL and Access back end tables or different copies? Can't you just use your backup file instead?

Comment: I can and am using my backup, it points to all of the same linked tables and  all of the linked data is fine, i cant even get to the switchboard form, it errors out before i see anything. i was just trying to figure out the why and how of the file itself breaking itself just in case this happens to a file that has local tables (i am in the process of converting them all to SQL server tables, but there are literally hundreds of access databases.)

Comment: So you're working OK; you're just worried in case you get a similar problem with a database that you haven't got a good backup of? Looks like some serious corruption of your db. Can you create a new blank db and copy all the objects from your corrupted db? Failing that, then I'm all out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: I just tried to do an import where id grab objects out, but it gave the error. though, on a secondary more interesting note, i was able to access every table in the database by doing a
`Select * from MSysObjects in 'C:\apps\Borked.accdb'` query and the like. (i renamed it borked because it is lol.)

Comment: Was going to make this an edit, but i took too long to type it. 

The important part was that i could recover the table data in case the table was local because there are some database files where its not using a split front end back end. i do have a backup of every file, just not necessarily a up to date copy of the table data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was a network error while accessing the database file on a network share. That caused internal corruption in a way that I don't really understand, and can not repair with a compact and repair. The good news is, a query that specifies the database file as a source CAN access data from any tables said database has, the bad news is, if there are any objects like forms, reports, or code modules that you do not have a backup of, you are out of luck.

The moral of the story? Keep good backups and don't use local tables.